# Determine enum case with section

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am implementing a `UITableView` which will have multiple sections. The amount of sections are dynamic. This are some properties:

```
public struct User { 
    let userRole: UserRole
}

public enum UserRole: Int, CaseIterable { 
    case superUser, admin, recruiter
}
```

My `UITableView` holds an array of `users`. The amount of sections are the amount of distinct `userRoles` in the array of `users`. Later on, I need to determine how many rows there are in each section with this function:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {}
```

I am wondering what the most clean/fastest way is to return the amount of rows in that section. Imagine the `user` array holds 2 `users`, one has a `userRole` of `superUser` and the other `recruiter`. The sections are 0 and 1, although the enum raw values are 0 and 2.

I have no idea how to return the correct amount of rows in that section in a clean way.  This is what I was writing, but stopped since I though there must be a better way:

```
extension Array where Element: User {
    func contains(userRole: UserRole) -> Bool {
        return contains(where: { $0.userRole == userRole })
    }
}

private func determineUserRoleForSection(section: Int) -> UserRole {
    let containsSuperUser = users.contains(userRole: .superUser)
    let containsAdmin = users.contains(userRole: .admin)
    let containsRecruiter = users.contains(userRole: .recruiter)

    switch section {
    case 0:
        if containsSuperUser {
            return .superUser
        }

        if containsAdmin {
            return .admin
        }

        if containsRecruiter {
            return .recruiter
        }
    case 1:
        // Repeat without superUser case
    case 2:
    default: fatalError()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a proper data model for the table view. When you have multiple sections in a table view you essentially want an array of arrays, not a single array.

Comment: @rmaddy Hmm thanks for the tip, never thought about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the recommendation of having a model, you could do something like this:

```
public struct UsersViewModel {
    var users: [User]
    private var sections: [UserRole: [User]] {
        return [
            .admin : users.filter { $0.userRole == .admin },
            .superUser : users.filter { $0.userRole == .superUser },
            .recruiter : users.filter { $0.userRole == .recruiter }
        ]
    }
    var superUserSections: Int { return sections[.superUser]!.count}
    var adminSections: Int { return sections[.admin]!.count }
    var recruiterSections: Int { return sections[.recruiter]!.count }
}
```

And then it'd just be a matter of using:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfSections section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3 // section 0 is superUser, section 1 is admin, section 2 is recruiter.
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {
    case 0:
        return viewModel.superUserSections
    case 1:
        return viewModel.adminSections
    case 2:
        return viewModel.recruiterSections
    }   
}
```